# Why systemd service files don't know common $PATH?

Tags: systemd

As question states, why every systemd service files have full path of programs, for example:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/coolprogram
```

when it could just be

```
ExecStart=coolprogram
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because SystemD starts at a point when there doesn't exist a proper environment and $PATH isn't defined. Also, you want to make sure that you get the correct executable even if it is not in the $PATH or something else is (e.g. something malicious).

Why is this a problem for you?

Comment: I never said that it's a problem, I just wanted an explanation. But this wonderful community that can't wait to vote negative for question is so awesome and supportive. Anyways, thanks for answer.